# failed to resolve com.github.KingsMentor:MobileVisionBarcodeScanner:2.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-2.0

[image: screenshot]

I tried going to the github link https://github.com/KingsMentor/MobileVisionBarcodeScanner
but I didn't find any readme doc, please advise?

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle(Project) add following at the end of your dependencies

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

In your build.gradle(app) add following with the correct version number

```
compile 'com.github.KingsMentor:MobileVisionBarcodeScanner:2.0.0'
```

I see you have version 1.3.0 in your gradle file, this may be the cause.

Comment: I added it but it didn't work, thank you for your advice.

Comment: Did you also add jitpack repository to your build.gradle?
allprojects {
 repositories {
  ...
  maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
 }
}

Comment: yes I did. Can you tell me where the xyz library is supposed to go? maybe I put it in the wrong place.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please see. You can see here that the repository status is OK so it should work fine. https://jitpack.io/#KingsMentor/MobileVisionBarcodeScanner

Comment: I added implementation 'xyz.belvi.mobilevision:barcodescanner:2.0.3' to the project after snooping around on the github site and it seemed to resolve the errors at build but I'm not sure how it used to perform during runtime.